# Treat text as inseparable?

Tags: html, css

I have a paragraph of text and would like to make sure that one phrase of that paragraph is never broken up between lines. How can I do that?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this would be for displaying to the end-user, try using a non-breaking white-space: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space

Comment: I'm plussing you just for linking to that overwhelming wikipedia page instead of just saying &nbsp;

Comment: Some browsers will break up hyphens, so that would be a problem.

Comment: @Andrew: Non-breaking spaces and hyphens are not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I can think of is to wrap the phrase in a span tag and add the following css.

```
#myspan
{
    white-space: nowrap; 
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9kmaK/5/

white-space info: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#white-space

Answer (score 0):

I may be mis-interpreting your question, but if you're looking for way to not line-wrap in HTML, look up the "white-space" property. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp